# GROUP BY with WHERE shows nothing

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, where-clause

I have this

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT *, COUNT(*) FROM impressions WHERE pub_tag = '$pub_tag' AND pub_id = '$pub_id' AND month = '$date' GROUP BY country");
while($stat_cont = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo '[\''.$stat_cont['country'].'\', '.$stat_cont['COUNT(*)'].'],';
}
```

it shows nothing also gives no error. When remove the WHERE then it works.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `impressions` (
  `id` int(15) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pub_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `pub_tag` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `month` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ip` int(15) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `country_city` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `country_region` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `country_code` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `revenue` float unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;
```

Comment: Show database dump please, then we can determine whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your query into a variable and `echo` it to see what exactly is being sent to MySQL.

   `$stmt = "SELECT ... ";`
   `echo $stmt;`
2. Use aliases for aggregates:

   `SELECT Country, COUNT(*) AS count ...`
3. `mysql_` functions are deprecated. Please do not use them in new code. They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.
4. MySQL extends `GROUP BY` functionality that may produce undesired results. It's best practice to not select columns which are not in your `GROUP BY`

Comment: Please update your question with the code you are now using and any errors you are receiving.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the results by grouping "country", Instead of giving "*" in your query give country in select and group by.

Comment: Sorry the code is fine and it works the problem was with $pub_tag which was empty due to which there was problem.